# How do I use Kotlin functions exported to Javascript in browser?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

I'm trying to build some basic Kotlin code as a JS library. Just for testing, I want to be able to call some of this code right from a browser console.

Here is some of the code I'm working with.

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("js") version "1.5.10"
}

group = "..."
version = "..."

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

kotlin {
    js(LEGACY) {
        browser {
            webpackTask {
                output.libraryTarget = "global"
                output.library = "connect"
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
}
```

main.kt

```
package main


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello world! From Kotlin!")
}

fun testLog(string: String){
    console.log("test log")
    console.log(string)
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./connect.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this is what I get in the console.

[image: browser console output]

What am I missing?